# How to add an ampersand to an alphanumeric REGEX

Tags: regex

I have this Regex:

```
"^[-'\"\\sa-zA-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜàáâãäæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ0-9]*$"
```

And I want it to admit the ampersand character ("&"). How do we do this?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by admitting & ?

Comment: What program are you feeding your regex to?

Comment: My input field does not accept the character "&" with the Regex that I use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `&` between the brackets:

```
"^[-'\"\\sa-zA-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜàáâãäæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ0-9&]*$"
```

Test it here: http://regexr.com/3bbmm

Answer (score 2):

You can take a fresh `&` and drop it somewhere into your character class:

```
  ⇩ here  ⇩ better not here, this is a range
[-&'\"\\sa-zA-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜàáâãäæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ0-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

What application are you using? This might help us understand why the & is not accepted by itself. Could escaping the character help `\&`:

`^[-'\"\\sa-zA-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜàáâãäæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ0-9\&]*$`

Comment: There is no need to escape the `&` when it is between brackets. Check the link in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Diego. I wonder whether this answer may be applicable given the validation issue Chris claims to be having in his comment above..? I will edit the answer so that it is not giving false answers

Comment: your answer is OK, as I and some other are saying, Chris only has to add the `&` between the brackets. I just wanted to clarify that it doesn't have to be escaped although it works both ways.

Comment: @Chris has a comment on his question saying that the input field he is using does not accept the & character. Thanks for correcting my mistake, but we still haven't solved Chris' problem (although I think we probably have answered his question)

Comment: I believe Chris meant that he was using the regex to validate the value in an input field and, with his regex, the `&` wasn't a valid option.

Comment: Ah yes. That does make sense. Clearly it solves Chris' problem as he's accepted your answer! Time to leave this one alone :)

Answer (score -1):

Just add the & in the list of matched characters.

```
"^[-'\"\\sa-zA-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜàáâãäæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ0-9&]*$"
```